# Parsing Data From JSON in Discord Bot MAker

Tags: arrays, json, discord, bots

so working on a bot in Discord Bot Maker, I installed the JSON extension and while i can fetch the json its fetches as [object object] and for the life of me i cant figure out how in DBM to drill deeper and say grab the name field off the first entry or even how to specify it look at a particular entry

i have tried to use nesting when calling the variable so $.results.name but that just returns an empty array and no data but when i do $.results debug does show all the data im just not sure how to access it

[image]

here's the api I'm using btw
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[object Object] is just an object like this:

```
{ some: object }
```

All you need to do is

```js
JSON.stringify(object)
```

If you store the api object in a temp variable, go into a Run Script and type:

```js
const res = JSON.stringify(tempVars("varname"));
this.storeValue(res, 1, "res", cache);
```

Make sure to replace `varname` with your temp variable name. It will store a value `tempVars("res")` which you can use in a Send Message action.